# Encapsulating the query logic in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern, encapsulation

Recently, I came across a [blog post](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/build-reusable-testable-queries-part-1/) regarding the encapsulation of queries in EF Core. This approach is somewhat different from the repository pattern which is much more familiar to me.

In repository pattern, I follow an approach like this,

```
public interface ISomeRepo
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetAll();
    // Some other queries
}

public class SomeRepo : ISomeRepo
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetAll()
    {
        // Get data from database
    }
    // Implementation of other queries
}
```

But the approach which is described in the blog post is something like this,

```
public interface IModelQuery<out TResult, in TModel>
{
    IEnumerable<TResult> Execute(TModel model);
}

public class PartialMatchQuery : IModelQuery<string, IEnumerable<string>>
{
    private readonly string partial;
 
    public PartialMatchQuery(string partialString)
    {
        partial = partialString;
    }
 
    public IEnumerable<string> Execute(IEnumerable<string> model)
    {
        return model.Where(s => s.ToLower().Contains(partial));
    }
}
```

And querying the data source this way,

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    var strings = new List<string>() // I used an IEnumerable<T> implemented collection for simplicity
            {
                "Abhc", "Bmhh", "Csjudsm", "Dsjuh", "Ejhduhb", "Fmjasgh"
            };

    var query = new PartialMatchQuery("m");
    var result = query.Execute(strings).ToList();

    return 0;
}
```

I feel like this "new" approach is flexible compared to the repository pattern which contains a set of "strict" operations like `GetAll()`, `GetById()`, `Modify()` etc. On the other hand, with this `IModelQuery` thing, I could end up with 100 classes if I have 100 different queries. I searched the web for some real-world implementations of this new approach (at least new to me) but couldn't find any.

So, here are my questions:

1. Is it really worth to use this new approach over the repository pattern bearing the cost of " one class per one query"?
2. Are there any side-effects (that I had missed) of using this new approach that affects the maintainability or scalability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read the two-part blog and only the second part gets into implementing this with EF. Honestly all I see is a veritable crap-ton of wrapper code for what can simply be done via working with `IQueryable`.

In the micro-service world, patterns like this and CQRS may be useful where operations are scoped down to single entities. For most line of business applications drilling down to something like this would be prohibitively expensive and limiting.

It will need even more code to leverage asynchronous operations, and his test code implementation will not work with `async` operations.  This also does not work with projection, nor accommodate things like eager loading dependencies when working with more complex entity structures. In short, it is an exercise in futility. Most of the examples you will find on blogs and such cover only ridiculously simple use cases but you will soon discover in a real world solution that there are huge gaps that require even more code to try and address, more complexity, deviating from the "pattern", or ending up comping to a conclusion that "EF is too slow" because shoe-horning it into some abstraction that only succeeds in effectively crippling it.

EF does not *need* a repository pattern, it has one in the `DbSet` class. It does not need a Unit of Work pattern, as it has one in the `DbContext` class. This isn't to say that you cannot extract a Unit of Work or Repository pattern over it, but you need to be careful about the reason for the abstraction and choosing an implementation that does not cripple what EF can do.

My advice from reading that article? Avoid it. It needs more work to handle asynchronous operations, it does not easily accommodate projection (`Select` / `ProjectTo` etc.) and it does not accommodate eager loading (`Include`) or things like pagination without more methods, parameters, and/or complexity.

Absolutely avoid Generic Repository patterns with `IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()` and the like for all of the same reasons.

For most projects, especially for those developers are writing when starting out with EF, just use the `DbContext` and `DbSet`s and learn to count on projection for read operations, and eager loading for updates. Avoid things like detached entities including passing entities around between service layers, use DTOs or ViewModels that are projected.  If you later develop to a point where you want to leverage unit testing or are working on a system like a multi-tenant SaaS or something with a soft-delete implementation where you don't want to rely on EF's core filtering rules for soft-delete and have core domain rules then I can recommend a repository pattern, but leveraging `IQueryable<TEntity>` rather than returning `IEnumerable<TEntity>` or even `TEntity` directly. This type of repository can be easily mocked for unit testing and can encapsulate core domain rules, while remaining completely flexible to working with `async` operations, projection, eager loading, pagination, filtering, and sorting.

If working on a micro-service solution where it makes sense to break things down to individualized commands or queries that work completely independently and can be latched onto with observers and the like, then go hard with something like this. ;)

Comment: So, if I'm right what you are suggesting is directly query the `DBcontext` from the service layer, process the data and then pass them to the controllers.

Comment: Basically "do the simplest thing". A lot of best practices and suggestions like this stem from specific problems and use cases that developers may face in particular systems due typically to scale. The issue is that they cannot express these solutions in the vast context of the scenario they face, so they create simplistic example scenarios to try and demonstrate the solution they have, except those scenarios get absolutely no benefit from the complexity introduced by the solution. This has the side-effect that devs on new projects searching for "best practices" come across these examples....

Comment: ... and figure that must be the "proper" way to approach things. 99% (give or take, up for debate) of projects don't benefit at all from introducing complexities like this, especially when starting out. For simple projects I don't even have a service layer, controllers can interact with the DbContext/Dbsets and build their view models. A service layer makes sense if I have two or more distinct consumers that I want to share identical domain operations with, and that would communicate via DTOs. Again, 99% of the time that is not actually needed.

Comment: By "distinct consumers" I would be referring to things like an MVC controller and a separate Web API controller or other integration point into the domain. (WPF admin client, background service, etc.) not merely two controllers in the same web application.